# Async Lambda Issue

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Updated code (as per comment): still doesn't work

I am trying to create an extension method on `Task` to call my async database calls (fire and forget), however I am getting a compilation error:

> Error CS4010
>   Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<T>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task<T>, none of which are convertible to 'Func<T>'. AsyncTaskExtension

This is my code:

```
 public static void ExecuteTask<T>(this Task<T> BackgroudJob, Action<T> UIJob, Action<Exception> OnError = null) where T : struct
    {
        Func<T> work = async () =>
         {
             T ret = default(T);
             try
             {
                 ret = await BackgroudJob;
                 UIJob(ret);
                 //throw new Exception("My exception !!!");
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     if (OnError != null)
                     {
                         OnError(ex);
                     }
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                 }
                 catch { }//eat exception
             }

             return ret;
         };

        work();
    }
```

Comment: The type of `work` has to be `Func<Task<T>>`

Comment: if `Job` is awaitable, which it seems to be here, that means *something else has already started it running*.

Comment: What do you mean "fire and forget"? You're trying to return the result of doing the `work` in the last line, that doesn't sound very forgetful to me.

Comment: `return work()` was added in the last edit for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to create an extension method on Task to call my async database calls(fire and ferget)

OK, I have to say that this is a ***really***, really bad idea!

"Fire and forget" means: "I don't care when this code completes. Or *if* it completes." Corollary: "I am perfectly OK with losing database writes during an appdomain recycle, process recycle, reboot, or pod replacement; and I am happy with not having any logs or other notifications about said data loss."

I cannot imagine how this would ever be acceptable for a database write operation. At most, fire-and-forget is sometimes used for things like updating caches. Some people think it's OK for emails, too, but I prefer a simple queue.

To make the method fire-and-forget, change the return type to `void` and the `Func<T>` to an `Action`:

```
public static void CreateFireAndForgetWork<T>(this Task<T> Job, Action<Exception> OnError = null) where T : struct
{
  Action work = async () =>
  {
    try
    {
      await Job;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ...
    }
  };
  work();
}
```

This code does result in an `async void` lambda expression (since it is converted to an `Action`). Normally, this is a bad idea, but it's here because the code is doing fire-and-forget (which, as noted at the beginning of this post, is a bad idea IMO).

Comment: whole idea is I am trying to avoid Async Void all over the place on UI. Please don't get confused by method name I am going to change it to more meaningful name later, I am more worried about compile time error, here is my updated signature apologies for confusion

public static void ExecuteTask<T>(this Task<T> BackgroudJob, Action<T> UIJob, Action<Exception> OnError = null) where T : struct

Comment: Why are you attempting to use async delegates if you're wanting to avoid `async` method signatures? Why not just use the `ThreadPool` or a `BackgroundWorker` which would ensure the job finishes without blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @ColinM: The UI thread (if any) wouldn't be blocked either way. If you need to prevent continuations from being scheduled on the UI thread, I'd recommend `Task.Run`.

Comment: @RahulLore: Why would you like to avoid `async void`? I would say that `async void` is acceptable for fire-and-forget. Whether fire-and-forget is acceptable in this particular instance is a completely different question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put an "also" in that sentence to read "which would also ensure the job finishes without blocking the UI thread". The suggestion of `ThreadPool` or `BackgroundWorker` was due to Rahul's ambition to avoid `async void` or `async Task`

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally it worked

```
public static void ExecuteTask<T>(this Task<T> BackgroudJob, Action<T> UIJob, Action<Exception> OnError = null) where T : struct
    {
        Action work = async () =>
         {
             T? ret = null;
             try
             {
                 ret = await BackgroudJob;
                 //throw new Exception("My exception !!!");
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     if (OnError != null)
                     {
                         OnError(ex);
                     }
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                 }
                 catch { }//eat exception
             }

             if (ret.HasValue)
             {
                 UIJob(ret.Value);
             }
         };
        work();
    }
```